# Cannot get “vagrant up” to work when running Laravel Homestead

Tags: vagrant

I cloned `git clone homestead` and changed `Homestead.yaml` as following Laravel Homestead documentation and when I did command `vagrant up` that's caused bellow the error.

I am using Vagrant 2.2.14 with VirtualBox on Windows 10 and am using Visual Studio.

I tried:

```
rm vagrant
```

And:

```
vagrant init
```

But it’s not working.

Here is the error:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    homestead: Box Provider: virtualbox
    homestead: Box Version: >= 11.0
==> homestead: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
The box you're attempting to add has no available version that
matches the constraints you requested. Please double-check your
settings. Also verify that if you specified version constraints,
that the provider you wish to use is available for these constraints.

Box: laravel/homestead
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
Constraints: >= 11.0
Available versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.3.0, 0.3.3, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.4, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 4.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.4.0, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.1, 8.0.0.pre.alpha1, 8.0.0.pre.alpha2, 8.0.0.pre.alpha3, 8.0.0.pre.alpha4, 8.0.0.pre.beta, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.1.0, 8.2.0, 8.2.1, 9.0.0, 9.0.1, 9.1.0, 9.1.1, 9.2.0, 9.3.0, 9.4.0, 9.5.0, 9.5.1, 9.6.0, 9.6.1, 9.7.2, 10.0.0, 10.1.0, 10.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like someone edited the scripts/homestead.rb file on line 22

[screenshot of code edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSqgw.jpg)

change '>= 11.0' to '>=10.0' and it should work

You could also checkout the older branch: 18.04
the problem was merged on the 26th of december, the older branch does not have the issue.